# Python String Type error

Tags: python, types

```
word = input("Please enter two words");
word1 = word
number = len(word);
space = '/'  
for i in range(number):
    if(word1[i] == " "):
        word1[i] = space;
print(word1)
```

I am getting the following error: "TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment"
It doesn't like that I am replacing word1[i] = space;
I don't understand why because they are both strings.

Comment: While a string can be indexed and iterated over in python, it cannot be assigned by index. You have to do `word1 = word1[:i] + space + word1[i+1:]` instead.

Comment: Next time, please at least Google the error message before posting a new question.

Comment: word.replace(" ","/")

Comment: Oh wow I did not it was immutable in python. I tried the solution that you gave me and it worked perfectly! thank you so much, if you change it to an answer I can select it. Thanks again! @EliSadoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as the error message says, you can't modify a string.

One approach, which will let you keep most of the code you've written, is to convert your string to a list of characters:

```
word = list(word)
```

Then join it back into a sting when you're done:

```
word = "".join(word)
```

Another approach is to build up a new string and conditionally choose which character is concatenated to it:

```
result = ""
for c in word:
    if c = " ":
        result += space    # should be named slash
    else:
        result += c
```

But a far better solution is to replace all that code with a single line:

```
word = word.replace(" ", "/")
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are in python immutable, which means, their elements cannot be changed or rearranged.

Try creating a new string and put your characters inside it.